# Console stay silent after some time of usage while using wireless debugging

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I have repeated problems with wireless debugging that moves from one update to another. Console stops outputting after some minutes of use. Then I have to do `adb  kill-server`  and ask god that it actually starts working or try Logcat to find if I have some luck there. Pretty annoying and lowering my productivity that wireless debugging was suposed to improve I believe.

I am not sure if I have to live with this, go back to cable or is there other solution.

[image]

Comment: If the phone goes into power save mode a lot of devices disconnect Wifi. A disconnected Wifi may explain the adb interruptions. Alternatively all the other network devices in between your PC and the phone can also prob unused Wifi connections. I would check if the connections stays alive if you execute something via adb that produces output all the time, e.g. a ping command o the phone.

Comment: @Robert debugging works, just console output fails